# How to make snowflake icon on stackexchange's #topbar dashboard less irritating?

Tags: bug, design

Whenever SE page loads, `#topbar` dashboard gets displayed without snowflake icon.

When page assets finishes loading and jQuery kicks in, snowflake icon http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash2013/img/topbar-snowflake.png appears on dashboard.

Since there is a noticeable delay between two events described above, sudden icon appearance creates a visual irritation which draws little more  attention to itself than it should be (there was no events on dashboard, just regular page loading).

NB: I'm indifferent toward Winter Bash game, so I neither love hats, nor hate them, but simply got tired of looking at the `#topbar` just to figure out what nothing of interest happened.

---

Step to reproduce: reloading page from browser cache causes blinking effect on snowflake icon.

Comment: Wait another 3 days and it'll resolve itself....

Comment: Same happens in the profile... once the page is loaded everything jumps down a few pixels while the snowflake appears :-(.

Comment: You can just block all files under `http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash2013` and you will not have any snow flake, or hats.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, please post your solution as an answer. It looks like URL filtering works best with web-design :-)

Comment: @user153949 if you insist... ;)

Comment: The delayed load of the snowflake is irritating as it looks like a notification. I understand the delay on the hats themselves but I don't see why the snowflake has the delay

Comment: @RichardTingle the snowflake and hats are loaded via the same script, which is loading only after everything else finish loading. It's technically possible to separate them of course, but probably the dev didn't see any reason to do that.

Comment: I must admit I'm staggered this is getting downvoted. Possibly needs a more neutral tone, but is a very fair point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you really don't want that poor flake around you can just block it.

The whole thing is loaded from this root URL: `http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash2013`.

Block this, and you'll see neither flakes nor hats.

Comment: Thank you. SO devs sometimes being little too pushy with *fun stuff* they introducing, and this solution fixes semi-blinking icon issue without having me to express any hatred toward headgear (which I do not have anyway). Meanwhile I figured out an another URL for script: `||winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/api/*`

Comment: That's your full right, @user153949 - thanks for the cool pirate hat! ;)

Answer (score 6):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). However, wait until January 4th and it will be [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro). However, if you hate [winterbash](/questions/tagged/winterbash), you can click the I hate [hats](/questions/tagged/hats) button, in which case you are a [hat](/questions/tagged/hat)er

Comment: ... unless skeleton code gets reused in Spring Bash game :-)

Comment: There's a spring bash?!

Comment: @scrblnrd3 We maybe need to ask sceptic.SE to see what they have to say on **Spring Bash 2014**?!

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem, as some people (myself included) would like to keep the hats **and** not have the delayed loading on the snowflake (delayed hat loading is less irritating)

Answer (score 2):

This is by design, the whole hat magic is loaded by JS and is not pre-baked into the page. After all, this is a temporary feature.

You can stop this behavior by clicking the "I hate hats" link, after which there will be no annoying snowflake.

Comment: By some weird design, on the primary website of my interest (SO) I can **love hats** only. To **hate hats** I have to visit `meta` instead. There must be some opt-in/opt-out confusion.

Comment: @user153949 This means that you have not opted in on stack overflow. The hate hats link will appear after you love hats. If you currently see the "I love hats" link, this means that you should not be shown any hat related stuff.

Comment: Yes, but by some reason I see "I hate hats" and hats in your profile on meta.

Comment: @user153949 you've not turned it off on meta. You need to click "I hate hats" everywhere, though I think it gives an option to hate hats globally

Answer (score 2):

This blinking icon on the top bar appears (to my eye at least) as a notification; this has tricked me an embarrassingly large number of times.  As such I would support this being changed to a normal top bar button for winter bash next year so that people (like me) who love hats can avoid this problem.

The slow loading hats on the other hand are less of a problem as they don't look like notifications

Comment: Thats exactly my point. Top bar is a dashboard by essence, so this spurious activities will train users to pay less attention.